# Extend Report in C# for Multiple Test Classes is NOT working?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, testing, automation, extentreports

Base class is Report Class and Other two Test classes 1.TelerikOutlook and 2.UnitTest1
I am Extended Report class in to Both Classes but in html Report file only last test report details is displayed

it is Not working properly the Report is Generated but contains only last test class

```
    using AventStack.ExtentReports;
    using AventStack.ExtentReports.Reporter;
    using NUnit.Framework;
    using NUnit.Framework.Interfaces;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace Outlook
    {
    public class Report
    {

        protected ExtentReports _extent;
        protected ExtentTest _test;

        public Report()
        { }

        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public void BeforeClass()
        {
            try
            {
                //To create report directory and add HTML report into it

                _extent = new ExtentReports();
                var dir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.Replace("\\bin\\Debug", "");
                DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(dir + "\\Test_Execution_Reports");
                var htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(dir + "\\Test_Execution_Reports" + "\\Automation_Report" + ".html");
                _extent.AddSystemInfo("Environment", "Journey of Quality");
                _extent.AddSystemInfo("User Name", "Sanoj");
                _extent.AttachReporter(htmlReporter);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw (e);
            }

        }

        [SetUp]
        public void BeforeTest()
        {
            try
            {
                _test = _extent.CreateTest(TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw (e);
            }
        }


        [TearDown]
        public void AfterTest()
        {
            try
            {
                var status = TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Status;
                var stacktrace = "" + TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.StackTrace + "";
                var errorMessage = TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Message;
                Status logstatus;
                switch (status)
                {
                    case TestStatus.Failed:
                        logstatus = Status.Fail;
                        //  string screenShotPath = Capture(driver, 
      TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name);
                        _test.Log(logstatus, "Test ended with " + logstatus + " – " + errorMessage);
                        // _test.Log(logstatus, "Snapshot below: " 
      +_test.AddScreenCaptureFromPath(screenShotPath));
                        break;
                    case TestStatus.Skipped:
                        logstatus = Status.Skip;
                        _test.Log(logstatus, "Test ended with " + logstatus);
                        break;
                    default:
                        logstatus = Status.Pass;
                        _test.Log(logstatus, "Test ended with " + logstatus);
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw (e);
            }
        }

        [OneTimeTearDown]
        public void AfterClass()
        {
            try
            {
                _extent.Flush();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw (e);
            }
        }




    }
}
```

Telerik class extends Report class

```
Test case 1 ->


    using NUnit.Framework;
    using System;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Automation;
    using TestStack.White;
    using TestStack.White.Configuration;
    using TestStack.White.InputDevices;
    using TestStack.White.UIItems;
    using TestStack.White.UIItems.Finders;
    using TestStack.White.UIItems.WindowItems;

    namespace Outlook
    {

    [TestFixture]
      public class TelerikOutlook : Report
    {



        [Test]
        public void TestMethod()
        {
          _test =  _extent.CreateTest("TestMethod");

            var outlook_path ="C:\\jUsers\\ajay.b\\AppData\\Local\\Apps\\2.0\\
                            OA613NLD.BW2\\PTQ504M2.OJL\\tele..tion_0ec16cac1aa370e1_0    
                   7e2.0002_8d746ee446d800cb\\TelerikOutlookInspiredApp.EXE";


            // launch the application
            var application = Application.Launch(outlook_path);
            //Thread.Sleep(70000);

            //Application Window
            var window = application.GetWindow("My Application");


            // wait till window visible
            window.WaitTill(delegate () { return window.Visible; });

            var calendarBtn = window.Get(SearchCriteria.ByText("Calendar"));
            Mouse.Instance.Location = calendarBtn.ClickablePoint;
            Mouse.Instance.Click();

            //Calendar window
            var calendar = application.GetWindow("mark@telerikdomain.com - calendar");


            #region Current Month View
            var day = calendar.Get(SearchCriteria.ByText("26"));
            Mouse.Instance.Location = day.ClickablePoint;
            Mouse.Instance.Click();
            #endregion


            #region Create Appointment

            //to enable Create Appointment Button
            Point p = new Point(674, 377);
            Mouse.Instance.Click(p);

            //click on create appointment Buttton
            var appointment = calendar.Get(SearchCriteria.ByText("Create appointment"));
            // var list = calendar.Get(SearchCriteria.ByText("03-02-2020 00:00:00"));
            Mouse.Instance.Location = appointment.ClickablePoint;
            Mouse.Instance.Click();

            //Get Window of Create Appointment
            var appointmentWindows = application.GetWindows();
            Window appointmentWindow = null;
            foreach (var item in appointmentWindows)
            {
                if (item.Name == "Telerik.Windows.Controls.AppointmentDialogViewModel")
                {
                    appointmentWindow = item;
                }
            }
            //appointmentWindow = application.GetWindow("Appointment-Untitled");

            //Subject Input field
            var subject = appointmentWindow.Get<TextBox>( 
           SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("SubjectTextBox"));
            // CoreAppXmlConfiguration.Instance.BusyTimeout = 20000;
            // subject.ClickAtCenter();
            Mouse.Instance.Location = subject.ClickablePoint;
            Mouse.Instance.Click();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Keyboard.Instance.Enter("Automated Subject of appointment");

            //Description Input field
            var description = appointmentWindow.Get<TextBox> 
         (SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("DescriptionTextBox"));
            Mouse.Instance.Location = description.ClickablePoint;
            Mouse.Instance.Click();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Keyboard.Instance.Enter("Automated Description of appointment");

            //Start time input
            var startDate = appointmentWindow.Get(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("PART_DateTimeInput"));
            Mouse.Instance.Location = startDate.ClickablePoint;
            Mouse.Instance.Click();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Keyboard.Instance.Enter("06-02-2020 00:00");


            //save n close of appointment
            var okBtn = appointmentWindow.Get(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("OKButton"));
            Mouse.Instance.Location = okBtn.ClickablePoint;
            Mouse.Instance.Click();
            #endregion

            #region Drag N Drop Element

            //getting appointment element and drop at any date 
            var drag = calendar.Get(SearchCriteria.ByText("abcd : 06-02-2020 00:00:00 - 06-02-2020 
          00:00:00"));
            var drop = calendar.Get(SearchCriteria.ByText("03-02-2020 00:00:00"));
            Point d = drag.ClickablePoint;
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            application.WaitWhileBusy();
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            // drag.Click();
            // Mouse.Instance.DragAndDrop(drag,drop);
            // Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Mouse.Instance.Click(d);
            Mouse.LeftDown();
            // Thread.Sleep(2000);
            var stepCount = 30;
            var stepAmount = (float)(drag.ClickablePoint.Y - drop.ClickablePoint.Y) / stepCount;
            for (var i = 0; i < stepCount; i++)
            {
                Mouse.Instance.Location = new Point(Mouse.Instance.Location.X, Mouse.Instance.Location.Y 
        - stepAmount);
                Thread.Sleep(75);
            }
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Mouse.LeftUp();
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            #endregion

            application.Close();


        }

      }
     }
```

UnitTest1 extends Report class

```
Testcase 2-

     using System;
    using System.IO;
    using TestStack.White;
    using TestStack.White.UIItems.Finders;
    using TestStack.White.Factory;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using Outlook1 = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Linq;
    using TestStack.White.UIItems;
    using TestStack.White.UIItems.WindowItems;
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
    using AventStack.ExtentReports;
    using AventStack.ExtentReports.Reporter;

    namespace Outlook
    {
     [TestClass]
      public class UnitTest1 : Report
     {




       [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod12()
        {


        _test = _extent.CreateTest("TestMethod12");
            //var outlookPath = Path.Combine(
            //    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86),
            //    @"Microsoft Office\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE");
            //var application = Application.Launch(outlookPath);
            var outlook_path = "C:\\jProgram Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\OUTLOOK.EXE";

            //verify the path 
            Assert.AreEqual(outlook_path, "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft 
                          Office\\root\\Office16\\OUTLOOK.EXE");

            // launch the application
            var application = Application.Launch(outlook_path);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            //verify the launched application
            Assert.AreEqual(application.Name, "OUTLOOK");

            // var windows1 = application.GetWindows();
            // get explorer window
            var explorer = application.GetWindow("Inbox - ajay.bhosale@afourtech.com - Outlook");
            explorer.DisplayState = DisplayState.Maximized;
            //verify the screen 
            Assert.AreEqual(explorer.Name, "Inbox - ajay.bhosale@afourtech.com - Outlook");

            // click "New E-mail" button to start composing new email
            var newEmailBtn = explorer.Get(SearchCriteria.ByText("New Email"));
            newEmailBtn.Click();
            //verify  "New E-mail" Button is clicked
            Assert.IsTrue(newEmailBtn.Enabled);

            // get composer window
            var composer = application.GetWindow(
            SearchCriteria.ByText("Untitled - Message (HTML) "),
            InitializeOption.NoCache);


            //verify create appointment window
            Assert.AreEqual(composer.Name, "Untitled - Message (HTML) ");

            // fill out "To" field
            var toField = composer.Get<TextBox> 
       (SearchCriteria.ByClassName("RichEdit20WPT").AndByText("To"));
            toField.Enter("ajay.bhosale@afourtech.com");

            //verify input text of "To" field
            Assert.IsTrue(toField.Text.Equals("ajay.bhosale@afourtech.com"));

            // fill out "Subject" field
            var subjectField = composer.Get<TextBox> 
         (SearchCriteria.ByClassName("RichEdit20WPT").AndByText("Subject"));
            subjectField.Enter("Test Automated UI email");

            //verify input text of "Subject" field
            Assert.IsTrue(subjectField.Text.Equals("Test Automated UI email"));

            //var message = composer.Get(SearchCriteria.ByText("Untitled Message"));
            //message.Enter("asdfghjklkjhgfdsasdfghjkkjhgfdssdfghjklkjhgfds");
            //Thread.Sleep(2000);

            //var message = composer.Get(SearchCriteria.ByText("Message"));
            //message.GetType();
            //message.SetValue("Automated appointment message");
            //message.Enter("Automated appointment message");

            //change focus to get Outlook process registered in running object table

            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            var windows = WindowFactory.Desktop.DesktopWindows();
            //Thread.Sleep(20000);
            var desktop = windows.Last().GetElement(SearchCriteria.ByClassName("SysListView32"));
            // Thread.Sleep(15000);
            desktop.SetFocus();


            Thread.Sleep(15000);
            Outlook1.Application outlookCom = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application") as Outlook1.Application;
            var sentMailItem = outlookCom.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem as Outlook1.MailItem;
            var body = sentMailItem.Body;
            //var body = sentMailItem.HTMLBody;
            //var index = body.IndexOf(@"</body", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            //var index1 = body.IndexOf(@"</p", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            var bodydata = "Hi, " + "     " + "\n      This is an Automated Email.  \n" + "Thanks & Regards   \n" + "Afourtech Pvt Ltd.  ";

            //sentMailItem.HTMLBody = body.Insert(bodydata);
            sentMailItem.Body = body.Insert(1, bodydata);

            //click on send button
            var send = composer.Get(SearchCriteria.ByText("Send").AndByClassName("Button"));
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            send.Click();


            //verify save and close button is clicked
            Assert.IsFalse(send.Visible);

            // give Outlook time to send off the email
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

            application.WaitWhileBusy();
            explorer.Close();
            application.Close();
        }





    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the test classes extend the Report class, then the [OneTimeSetUp] will run before each class. You can create a new class marked [SetUpFixture] for the [OneTimeSetUp] and [OneTimeTearDown] methods, and this way they will only run before/after ALL test classes.

Answer (score 0):

What Andrea says here worked for me.
I have a Base Test class that is inheriting from the `Reporter` class. And my test classes inherit Base.

I added `[SetUpFixture]` to my `Reporter` class and then added the methods for `OneTimeSetUp` and `OneTimeTearDown` here.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30957269)